# ClickOnce fails to initialize with no network

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have an application that I have just added ClickOnce to as an update method. I'm about to pull it and do something else, even after working through all the gotchas of dealing with ClickOnce in a moderately complex application. Well, it's not even a complex application, but it's going onto dedicated hardware, so I have a few odd requirements, like completely transparent and automatic updates, no odd little pup-up windows, etc. The main one is that the application starts and takes over the system at boot.

Where this causes trouble for ClickOnce is that when the system first boots, there is no network - the Wi-Fi is still getting started and connecting. The application handles this, checking for the network to get started and then connecting to our server. ClickOnce is a different matter. If there is no network when the application starts, then all the ApplicationDeployment functions will not work, even after the network is started.

So, for example, I use something like this to get the version:

```
   if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
       Version = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
   else
       Version = "unknown";
```

If I run the application at boot (that is, before the network is working), this code will return "unknown" for the rest of the application run, even after the network is up. If I shut down the application and restart it, it shows the deployed version. So technically, the IsNetworkDeployed is returning an incorrect value. The application WAS network deployed; it's just not on a network NOW. I'll probably post this as a bug over on MSDN.

BTW, the application does not actually require a network to run, so at startup, I can't take the path of "wait until the network is ready, then restart the application automatically". The hardware can move around, and may be in the middle of nowhere with no available network at all. I still have to deal with that (and I don't actually return "unknown" for that case, I just pull the version from the assembly). And if the problem was just getting a version, I wouldn't care, but this means that there is no way to ever update the application, since it always starts with no network, and it will never get to my code to check for, download, and auto-update the application.

Before I write off all my ClickOnce work, I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to reinitialize ApplicationDeployment, so that it will figure out that there is a network and enable all that ClickOnce goodness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically what that check is doing:

```
    private static bool _isNetworkDeployed;
    private static bool _isNetworkDeployedChecked;

    public static bool IsNetworkDeployed
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_isNetworkDeployedChecked)
            {
                _isNetworkDeployed = (
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain != null &&
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext != null &&
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext.Identity != null &&
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext.Identity.FullName != null);
                //_isNetworkDeployed = ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed;
                _isNetworkDeployedChecked = true;
            }
            return _isNetworkDeployed;
        }
    }
```

We ran into the same issue with ClickOnce and reverse engineered the check. You could modify this to do your own checking prior to calling the .NET version.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that would have worked - cordon off all the ClickOnce stuff behind our own network checks.  Short-sighted design from Microsoft (yeah, I've never done that), but it does help to see what they're doing.  We've already built our own updater, though, which also gives us better security since we're using S3.